# Laravel Echo with Pusher and Livewire - not receiving notifications client-side

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, pusher, laravel-9, laravel-echo

I'm able to broadcast a notification to Pusher, but I'm unable to receive the response back in my livewire component.

Here is my Notification class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use App\Models\Statement;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class StatementCompletedNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Queueable;

    public $statement;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Statement $statement)
    {
        $this->statement = $statement;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database', 'broadcast'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => $this->statement->uploadedBy->id,
            'statement_id' => $this->statement->id,
            'file_name' => $this->statement->original_file_name
        ];
    }


    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('users.' . $this->statement->uploadedBy->id);
    }
}
```

And here is the `getListeners()` method on my Livewire component. I've tried several different things here, first off I tried the way it's shown in the docs, just by referencing my StatementCompletedNotification in the listener, like so:

```
    public function getListeners()
    {
        return [
            "echo-private:users.{$this->user->id},StatementCompletedNotification" => 'refreshNotifications'
        ];
    }
```

I noticed that in pusher, my event type is listed as `Illuminate\Notifications\Events\BroadcastNotificationCreated`, and I found [this post](https://www.guywarner.dev/laravel-livewire-private-notifications-with-echo-pusherjs) online, so I tried that method like so:

```
    public function getListeners()
    {
        return [
            "echo-private:users.{$this->user->id},.Illuminate\\Notifications\\Events\\BroadcastNotificationCreated" => 'refreshNotifications'
        ];
    }
```

Neither way has worked for me.

Here's where I'm attempting to just get something back in my javascript on the client-side:

```
    Echo.private('users.1')
        .notification((notification) => {
            console.log(notification);
        });
```

I don't get any response and I have no idea what the problem is. I've spent an insane amount of time on this and can't seem to figure it out.

Also, it appears that my notification is being picked up multiple times in the queue:

[image]

A little more background, the flow that I have set up right now is basically:

StatementCompleted event gets fired (not queued), there's a listener that handles the StatementCompleted event which is queued, and calls my StatementCompletedNotification class like so:

```
public function handle($event)
    {
        $event->statement->uploadedBy->notify(new StatementCompletedNotification($event->statement));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one, with "\" instead of "\\"

```
public function getListeners()
{
    return [
        "echo-private:users.{$this->user->id},.Illuminate\Notifications\Events\BroadcastNotificationCreated" => 'refreshNotifications'
    ];
}
```

Comment: The `.` helped me